# SQL query WHERE column IN (#list#) not returning any results

Tags: sql, xml, coldfusion, cfquery

I have the next simple query :

```
SELECT code, description 
FROM   table 
WHERE  code in ( #list# )
```

The list is created from an XML feed with listAppend():

```
<cfset list= listAppend(list, data.data1[i].xmltext )>
<cfset qualifiedList1 = ListQualify(list, "'")>
```

With listQualify I wrap every element from the list in quotation marks for the query. The problem is that when I run the query, I don't get any results back.

If I dump the list the query look like this :

```
SELECT code, description 
FROM   table 
WHERE  code in ('''BG/NN1'',''BG/NL2'',''BG/NN3'',''BG/NN4'',''BG/NN5''')
```

Any ideas on how can fix this problem?

> Update 1:
>   I've fixed the problem.The problem was with ListQualify(list, "'")>  Because list Qualify wraps every element in quotes the list attribute from cfqueryparam didn't recognized any of the values.Thank you!

Comment: Search for "parametrize IN clause", there are plenty of answers (splitting, temp table, table_variable, dynamic-SQL, ...)

Comment: @lad2025 plenty of answers *daily* at that.

Comment: The list attribute of the cfqueryparam tag is the solution to your problem.

Comment: As others have suggested, look at `cfqueryparm`. It does a good bit more than just properly formatting your list. But to put a little more to your issue, `('''BG/NN1'',....,''BG/NN5''')` isn't syntactically different than `('foo')`. Because of your quoting, you only have 1 element in your `IN` list.

Comment: ... not to mention that CF auto escapes embedded quotes turning ('foo') into (''foo''). Bottom line, *don't* manually quote. use cfqueryparam list like Dan Bracuk said.

Comment: @DanBracuk Hi, I've tried already the list attribute but this is what the SQL code ends up looking like: Select code, description from table where code in (?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: @user1673306 - The "?" are placeholders representing the literal values sent to the db, BG/NN1,BG/NN5....

Comment: So does it return results when using cfqueryparam? Make sure you're NOT quoting the list of values.

Comment: If cfqueryparam was the solution, you should ask @DanBracuk to promote his comment to an answer.